# Run a php line again after updating a row in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If possible to run again a php line after update a table in the database?

I have html button that fire a jQuery.post:

```
btn.onclick = function(e) {
    $.post('inc/pstPts.php',
          {
              pts: pts
          });
}
```

In pstPts.php I make the query and it update the target row with success.
I had loaded that row in a html with this:

```
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $i < $q->query_numrows(); $i++) { 
    print '<tr><td>' . $d[$i]['user_nom'] . ' ';
    print '<tr><td>' . $d[$i]['user_ape'] . ' ';
    print '<tr><td>' . $d[$i]['user_email'] . ' ';
    print '<tr><td>' . $d[$i]['user_cel'] . ' ';        }
?>
```

But this had loaded the old data.

I want to run just this 5 lines after the update.

Comment: title and question are very different.

Comment: Has been changed. Thanks.

Comment: then make the update, then select again, build the markup then replace that row with the response

Answer (score 0):

since you have very less code, i will just post pseudocode to give an idea.

**Server SIde:**

```
//get the inputs from $_POST

// update the database

$update = $db->update($_POST); //simplified. just an example

if($update !== false)
{
   $entry = $db->query("SELECT * FROM foo ...... WHERE id = $_POST['id']"); //take care of sql injections.

  foreach($entry as $i)
  {
      //build up the html and echo it
  }
}
```

**Note:** to bind the params (to make the query safe from sql injection), follow the examples in this [**binding links**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

**Client Side:**

```
$.post({
  //url
}).done(function(data){
      $('#selector').html(data);
});
```

done....

Comment: fyi: single quoted strings does not interpolate variables inside. just edit it and bind those vars.

Comment: oopsy, i did the opposite.

Comment: @wwwanaya then what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Basically what I want to do is, load the data that has been update. Think this: I have a html with a for loop that loads the data, in that html I have a button that updates the row in the database, what I want to do is load the new data. Something like see the data what's in the database in live mode.

Comment: above does _exactly_ that.